# Distance between multiset iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, multiset

Can we find the distance between two iterator in multiset with a complexity of less than O(n)?

I tried to use the std::distance() function provided with iterator header. But its internal implementation is O(n) for multiset iterator.

Comment: No, `O(n)` is the best you can do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`multiset::iterator` models BidirectionalIterator, not RandomAccessIterator, so `std::distance` is only required to be linear, not constant.